# Color of contributions in fviz_pca_var

Tags: r, pca

I have this matrix:

```
> res.pca
Standard deviations (1, .., p=3):
[1] 2.566251e+00 2.101037e+00 3.612421e-15

Rotation (n x k) = (11 x 3):
                       PC1         PC2         PC3
Gen_X_ray_h     0.23699015  0.37781446  0.01642690
Seas_Anod_curr -0.38942432  0.01701734 -0.13045632
Seas_HV_pos    -0.38958573  0.01009967 -0.10566531
Seas_fil_curr   0.38830136  0.03990639  0.10615347
Oil_part_cl_1  -0.38863910  0.03465617  0.58164037
Oil_part_cl_2  -0.16974725  0.42842353 -0.68370621
Oil_part_cl_3   0.02837364  0.47469213  0.09738151
Oil_humid       0.27301050 -0.33961377 -0.08741008
Oil_temp       -0.29184198  0.31538622  0.30267731
Oil_color       0.19608635  0.41130459  0.12437257
Oil_BDV        -0.33288663 -0.24741521 -0.17410376
```

through `res.pca <- prcomp(na.omit(df), scale = TRUE)`. But this results in this plot which lacks a color gradient or the like:

[image: img]

```
fviz_pca_var(res.pca
             , col.var = "contrib"
             , col.ind = "#000000"
             , gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07")
             , repel = TRUE 
             )
```

The command `ggplotly(fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", axes = 1, top = 10))` with the same object `res.pca` works flawlessly:

[image: img2]

Comment: All arrows are touching the circle meaning all vars have the same contribution and thus the same color. Are you sure that `fviz_contrib` uses the same data?

Comment: I was thinking the same but it does. I changed the data frame slightly, means, there is more input now and before that it worked without any issue. Means, I didn't touch the code except of the rows of the data frame..

Comment: It worked again, when I just ran the same code again for about 10 times without changing something. There must be glitch somewhere..   however, visually everything looks correctly now, when I changed na.omit(df) to na_replace(df). Does this make sense, is it even advisable?

Comment: Functions should not modify the inputs. I strongly advide using paradigms of Idempotence and copy on modify (which R does by default). Always run the code in a fresh and empty global environemnt.

Comment: What exactly is this idempotence? I'm aware of a lot of issues resp. mistakes on my side but this time it is definitely up to R :p

Comment: It's a word you can look up in dictionaries or the internet.

Comment: Thanks, you could also look up this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/